# Magento - Modify wsdl Definitions

Tags: api, magento, wsdl

I need to get an extra attribute from one of Magentos API calls. The sales order info request to be precise. I have found that the definitions in the wsi file (I am using WSI compliance for Java) for the complex object and I know I need to add a new field definition for the attribute that I want to come back in the response, however, how can you rewrite the WSI file to add in this new attribute?

I have made custom APIs for my Custom modules and I have extended existing APIs such as the catalog category module by adding new functions, but in this instance I simply need to have an additional attribute returned to me and it seems overkill to override the whole API for one line of XML definitions! Does anybody know of a way to rewrite the wsdl and wsi file or do I need to create my own function and extend the existing stuff?

Any thoughts or suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK this is one of the limitations and you are forced to modify a core *wsi.xml* file.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this was the case. Transpires that I need to encrypt this additional field now anyway, so simply going to extend core API.

Comment: All wsi.xml files are also merged so you can add new field in your module wsi.xml file.

Comment: Thanks Zyava. That is a useful bit of knowledge which I was unaware of. I'll try overriding the complex object and see if Magento will merge the XML. Thanks.